# How to group result by array column in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have such a table

```
id SERIAL,
user_id INT,
community_id INT[],
```

The table filled this way:

```
id | user_id | community_id 
1  |  1      |   {2, 4}
2  |  5      |   {2, 5} 
3  |  10     |   {2, 4}
```

I'd like to get COUNT of users which each community has, community_id is array cuz user can be in several community at the same time.

The query should be simple as:

```
SELECT community_id, COUNT(user_id) FROM tbl GROUP BY community_id
```

The result should be like this:

```
community_id  | user_count
2             |  3
4             |  2
5             |  1
```

I do not know how to `GROUP BY` array column. Can anybody help me ?

Comment: This query would be as simply as you expect, if the model was properly normalized.

Comment: can you be more specific ?

Comment: You have a classical one-to-many relationship. That shouldn't be represented with an array but with two tables. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Example

Comment: Please do not advise me to use junction table to implement MANY to MANY  relation. I am not developing the structure of database right now, I am trying to pull needed data from tables which already exist

Comment: Yes, that's my advice - **especially** because you expected the query to be "as simple as" it would be with a properly normalized model

Comment: I completely agree, but I have what I have.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `unnest()` to get a normalized view on the data, and the aggregate:

```
select community_id, count(*)
from (
  select unnest(community_id) as community_id
  from tbl 
) t
group by community_id
order by community_id;
```

But you should really fix your data model.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT unnest(community_id) community_id ,
       count(user_id) user_count
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY 1 --community_id = 1 and user_count = 2 (index of a column in select query)
ORDER BY 1
```

---

[unnest(anyarray)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE): *Expand an array to a set of rows*

i.e `select unnest(ARRAY[1,2])` will give

```
   unnest
   ------
       1
       2
```